# Parallel and Same magnitude

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vectors

In a rhombus, you would say that opposite sides are parallel, but the four sides are all equal in terms of magnitude.

Wouldn't things with the same gradient have the same magnitude which means that all of the 4 sides are parallel? Can someone correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: No. Magnitude ang gradient are different things. Say you have a circle around the origin. All points on the circle have the same magnitude of distance, but the gradient of the line to each point is different (in fact two diametrically opposed points have the same gradient)

Comment: @Andrei What if it is the other way around? I mean if you pythagoras on triangles that have the same gradient wouldn't it have the same magnitude? And for this rhombus case, would it be the same?